# Performance of postgres is very slow

Tags: postgresql, odoo, odoo-8

We are using postgres 9.1 for our openerp(odoo) application. Database size is 6GB and daily our customers post data so database size increases day by day. From past few weeks we very experiencing very slow performance in our application. Should I upgrade my database to version 9.6?

**Odoo Configuration**

```
db_host = False
db_port = 5432
db_password = False
xmlrpc_port=8069
limit_memory_hard = 8324800000
limit_memory_soft = 7120000000
max_cron_threads = 3 
workers = 6
auto_reload = False
longpolling_port = 8072
proxy_mode = 1
xmlrpc = True
xmlrpcs = True
xmlrpcs_port = 8071
limit_time_cpu = 600
limit_time_real = 600
```

**Hardware Information**

```
CPU- Intel Xeon 2.5 GHz Hexa core
RAM -18GB
```

**Postgres configuration**

```
max_connections = 80
maintenance_work_mem = 1GB
effective_cache_size = 13GB
work_mem = 112MB
wal_buffers = 8MB
shared_buffers = 4GB
default_statistics_target = 50
```

Comment: You must use a monitoring system. Slow performance doesn't mean, that your database is slow.

Answer (score 0):

@Bhanu , You should work on **postgresql.conf**. You need to change some settings like `max_connections,shared_buffers,effective_cache_size,work_mem,maintenance_work_mem,wal_buffers,default_statistics_target`.

Increase the size of these variables in config file as per your hardware configuration.

Comment: I have added my postgres config please tell me how much should I increase these values?

Comment: Can you please tell me the current size of shared_buffers whatever you have in your config?

Comment: shared_buffers = 4GB

Comment: Please share the size of following variables :-

max_connections,shared_buffers,effective_cache_size,work_mem,maintenance_work_mem,wal_buffers,default_statistics_target

Comment: I added this information in question, look in postgres configuration at the end of my question